# Simplify tensor-matrix operation with numpy.einsum or einops

Tags: numpy, einops

I have the following inputs:

- T: a (H x W x C) tensor, or if needed (H x W x C x 1).
- M: (C x C) matrix.

I need to compute a (H x W x C) tensor, in which each "slice" is the matrix product between M and the corresponding (1 x 1 x C) slice from T, like this:

```py
result = np.zeros_like(T)
for row in range(H):
    for col in range(W):
        result[row, col, ...] = M @ T[row, col, ...]
```

[image]

Can this be done more efficiently with numpy, numpy.einsum or einops?

Comment: You can try this : ```result = np.einsum("ijk,mk->ijm",T,M,optimize=True)```

Comment: Or `T @ M.T`, IIUC.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. Of course this works, thank you! Would you mind to elaborate a bit more in an answer (for example, is broadcasting involved?) so I can get it accepted? Maybe in hindsight the question might seem silly, maybe that's why it got downvoted, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere else and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Although Michael Szczesnys answer works, if performance and optimizations are not drastically better with the `@` solution, the einsum is much more readable. It might be just me, but a 3d+ dimensional tensors and broadcasting with transpositions involved are much harder to read than einstein subscripts